# Truetime Android API, how to get the values GMT, PST, device time automatic whenever open the activity?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time, current-time

I am using the API truetime-android.
https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android

My problem is, if i want to get the values GMT, PST, device time. I have to press the button Get Time Now. I don't like that, I want whenever I open that activity, the three GMT, PST, device time are already have the values, so i don't need to press button Get Time Now the get the values GMT, PST, device time. How to implement that?
[image]

Here is my code

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button refreshBtn;
private TextView timeGMT;
private TextView timePST;
private TextView timeDeviceTime;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity);
    setupUI();
    init(this);
    click() ;
}

public static void init(final Context context) {
(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
           TrueTime.build().withNtpHost("time.google.com").withLoggingEnabled(false).
           withSharedPreferencesCache(context).
           withConnectionTimeout(31428).initialize();
        } catch (IOException var2) {
            var2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
})).start();

private void click() {
    Date trueTime;
    refreshBtn!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        if (!TrueTime.isInitialized()) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
       trueTime = TrueTime.now();
       Date deviceTime = new Date();
       timeGMT.setText(formatDate(trueTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")));
       timePST.setText(formatDate(trueTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT07:00")));
       timeDeviceTime.setText(formatDate(deviceTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00"))));
        }
    }
}
private void setupUI() {
    refreshBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tt_btn_refresh);
    timeGMT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt_time_gmt);
    timePST = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt_time_pst);
    timeDeviceTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt_time_device);
}

private String formatDate(Date :date ,String : pattern,TimeZone : timeZone){
    String format = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    format.timeZone = timeZone;
    return format.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. You can find my changes as part of onCreate

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button refreshBtn;
private TextView timeGMT;
private TextView timePST;
private TextView timeDeviceTime;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity);
    setupUI();
    init(this);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
        if (TrueTime.isInitialized()) {
           trueTime = TrueTime.now();
           Date deviceTime = new Date();
           timeGMT.setText(formatDate(trueTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")));
           timePST.setText(formatDate(trueTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT07:00")));
           timeDeviceTime.setText(formatDate(deviceTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00"))));
        }
         }
        }, 1000);
}

public static void init(final Context context) {
(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
           TrueTime.build().withNtpHost("time.google.com").withLoggingEnabled(false).
           withSharedPreferencesCache(context).
           withConnectionTimeout(31428).initialize();
        } catch (IOException var2) {
            var2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
})).start();

private void click() {
    Date trueTime;
    refreshBtn!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
          if (!TrueTime.isInitialized()) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
       trueTime = TrueTime.now();
       Date deviceTime = new Date();
       timeGMT.setText(formatDate(trueTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")));
       timePST.setText(formatDate(trueTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT07:00")));
       timeDeviceTime.setText(formatDate(deviceTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00"))));
        }
    }
}
private void setupUI() {
    refreshBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tt_btn_refresh);
    timeGMT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt_time_gmt);
    timePST = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt_time_pst);
    timeDeviceTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tt_time_device);
}

private String formatDate(Date :date ,String : pattern,TimeZone : timeZone){
    String format = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    format.timeZone = timeZone;
    return format.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Well, if i opened SampleAcitivy for the first time, it didn't show me anything. But, if  i opened the SampleActivity again, then it showed the values. How to fix that?

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate it. Can you explain why add the handler make the code work?

Comment: sometimes code gets called before our UI initialize. This is the one way to delay our code execution. Or you can call the without handler in onResume. That might work.

Comment: Mark my answer as accepted if you find mine is helpful.